# gridengine-qmon package missing context help

Tags: 12.04, xorg, documentation

I upgraded to Precise and installed gridengine. The qmon GUI administrative tool still has the ancient X11 style interface from Sun Grid Engine, but when I click a Help button the "Context Help" popup dialog reports "There is no help available there."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `gridengine-qmon` package I do not find the old SGE help file called `qmon_help.ad`. There is just the manual page. The manual page lacks the context of the old dialogs, and it seems to be missing specific information I need for configuring the queue instances or the host resources (not sure which).

There is an X11 resource called `Qmon*contextHelpFile` set by default to `qmon_help`. I added the old help file to `/usr/share/gridengine` and set the X11 resource to the full pathname. This worked for me.